# Is Rylai's slow affected if I use Tiamat as well?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I'm using a single target spell (e.g. Annie's `Disintegrate`) with both Rylai's scepter and Tiamat equipped, does it cause the full 35% slow for ST abilities or 15% counting it as AoE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiamat only modifies basic attacks, *not* champion abilities. To this end, having Tiamat would do nothing to Annie's Disintegrate, which would still apply the full 35% Rylai's slow. Additionally, the splash from Tiamat is considered part of the basic attack, and does not apply a slow from Rylai's Crystal Scepter at all.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know Tiamat doesn't work for skills :(

Answer (score 0):

As answered above, Tiamat only applies on Autoattacks, but if you buy a Frozen Mallet and a Tiamat and Autoattack someone, you get the full slow, cause the Tiamat splash dmg and the Frozen Mallett slow apply simultaneously.

Comment: Are you completely sure? As far as i know, it only applies the actual damage, and not the on hit effects (AOE Madred's Bloodrazor much)?

Comment: As I said, Frozen Mallett applys the full slow on the Target you hit. That has nothing to do with the Tiamat Dmg.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood you then. (Tho explaining that on-hit effects dont interract with each other directly was kind of odd)